# How do I properly design a database schema for this scenario

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Suppose I owned a business that sold cars and motorcycles.  I want to track data on each.  My company provides a free warranty for every car, but we do not even offer warranties on motorcycles.  Initially, I thought I'd have two tables - a "Vehicles" table and a "Warranties" table, like this

```
Vehicles                                                     Warranties

VehicleID, SalePrice, VehicleType, WarrantyID                WarrantyID, EffDate, ExpDate
```

Where VehicleType is either "car" or "motorcycle".  My drawback to this is that, in the Vehicles table, every motorcycle would have a null value for "WarrantyID".  Would this be considered bad practice?

Another approach I've considered is using three tables like

```
Cars                                                         Motorcycles

VehicleID, SalePrice, WarrantyID                             Vehicle ID, SalePrice


Warranties

WarrantyID, EffDate, ExpDate
```

My drawback to this is that I'm separating motorcycles and cars into two tables that will almost be identical.  (In reality, they'll have more fields like purchase cost, mileage, etc).  The ONLY difference is that all cars will have a warranty and no motorcycles will have a warranty.

(Note: I'm also making the assumption that 2 or 3 cars could share a single warranty.)

What's the proper way to set up this database?

Comment: I think the first way is fine.  Just leave warrantyid null if a vehicle doesn't have one. You're not breaking any normalisation rules.

Comment: why are you making the assumption that more than one car can have the same warranty?

Comment: You said: _"I'm also making the assumption that 2 or 3 cars could share a single warranty."_. Can the opposite be true too? Can one car have multiple warranties?

Comment: I'm really designing a database for a workers compensation provider.  We have a complex system of deductible and guaranteed cost policies.  It's hard to explain so I tried to come up with an analogy that would make more sense.

Comment: One car cannot have more than one warranty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the motorcycles and cars in the same table.

It's totally ordinary to allow a column to be NULL when the attribute does not pertain to the type of data in a given row.  NULL is for "unknown, missing, or inapplicable data."

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you could consider a join table.

```
Vehicle              VehicleWarranty          Warranty
---------            ---------------          ----------
VehicleId            VehicleId                WarrantyId
SalePrice            WarrantyId               EffectiveDate
```

That way, there's no Warranty ID in your Vehicle table, so you don't have to deal with nulls.  There's only an entry in the Warranty table (and the VehicleWarranty table) if you have a warranty on a vehicle.  Further, the join table allows you to attach the same warranty to multiple vehicles, or the same car to multiple warranties.

Comment: "the join table allows you to attach the same warranty to multiple vehicles, or the same car to multiple warranties." Since this seems to run against the requirements, it is actually a weakness of this approach.

Comment: From the OP:  "(Note: I'm also making the assumption that 2 or 3 cars could share a single warranty.)"  So it's actually a requirement.

Comment: exactly, no need to combine one car with multiple warranties.

Comment: You probably want a vehicle type table too. This will give 3rd normal.

Comment: This would work.  However, according to Bill (see the answer below), there is no problem with having bunch of null values in a table.  So, is there any reason I should take this approach over the one I first suggested?  This way seems more elegant, but I'm not sure it's really any better than my first design.

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste.  I prefer not having to deal with nulls in my application logic.

Comment: @BenGorman You should take this approach if you want to support a many to many relationship, ie many vehicles to 1 warranty, or 1 vehicle with multiple warranties. If you never want a vehicle to have more than one warranty, but 1 warranty can be shared by multiple vehicles, the correct solution is Bill's. And add a vehicletype table (vehicetypeid in vehicles table). This will help you conform to 3NF, helping improve data quality and reduce disk space.

Comment: @dewd Thanks.  I think what you said makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper way, both approaches are valid. It depends what the business is all about.

Is it about Vehicles, i.e. a lot of stuff in the application deals with Vehicles, without caring if it is a Car or a Motorcycle, then you probably want one table.

But it is perfectly possible have separate tables, possibly with a view combining both, if most of the business deals with either one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use you're going to do on the tables.

If you will query lists of mixed vehicles then you should go for the first model.

But if you're not going to mix them you could use the second.

I would choose the first as it will let you to offer warranty for bikes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If warranty is optional for some vehicles and your assumption is not a requirement, you could put the FK in the Warranty table. The following also assumes that there is a one to one relationship between Vehicle and Warranty (if it exists).

```
Vehicle              Warranty
---------            ---------------
VehicleId            VehicleId
SalePrice            EffectiveDate
```

the drawback is that you would have to pay the price of an outer join or query for Warranty in order to find out if the vehicle came with one or not.

Its hard to tell what's best without knowing your query pattern.