# database design for this road map

Tags: mysql, oracle, google-maps, database-design, uml

I am thinking about the database schema for a road map and thinking about the best possible model.I have following queries in my mind that need to be tackled like

```
Do streets s1 and s2 intersect?
Get all streets adjacent to point of interest p.

OR 

Get the distance between entrance e1 and exit e2 on highway h.
Get the shortest route from intersection i1 to intersection i2.
```

I thought the table names should

```
roads and streets, including highways
governmental regions: states, counties, and local municipalities of cities, towns, villages
```

I have strong expertise in Database modeling, but this is first time I am creating a schema like this, Any help in this regard

As per SO rules, OP have to show some effort , I have seen some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904033/how-do-i-properly-design-a-database-schema-for-this-scenario) thats why I am asking for help in schema.

Comment: sounds like what you need is a geo engine (like oracle spatial) with a table containing points of interest with lat/lot coordinates and categories / types etc ...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know if roads intersect. The answer to that question should be in your database model.
It is the most important question you can have.

I would say that you need to organize your information around intersections. What road of which type is present at intersection at GIS location (x,y)?

There is only one table for roads, but each road can be of different types. Sometimes can a road be different types of road, yet have the same traffic rules. To get that distinction within the model would I make a distinction between type of road and effective type of road.

A first entrance for a data model is: http://www.osgeo.org/.

EDIT: take a look for instance at this link on that site:
http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html
There can you download a distribution that enables you to test different open source geospatial software.
This might be exactly what you are looking for:
http://mapguide.osgeo.org/

Comment: thank you but cant see anything related to DB models at the site

Comment: @user1765876: edited my answer and gave you some links on that site that might help you further.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to have nodes and edges - for inner solving your tasks. (short way and so on)
- You need the roads and streets and regions you have told about to translate from your inner model to human language. Also, don't forget the point objects: bus stops, crossroads, house entrances, phone booths, shops atd.
- So, you need two models and a structure and a set of methods for translation between them.

Inner model:

```
Table: NODE           Table: EDGE
Id                    Id
place(REGION.Id)      Start(Node.Id)
                      End (Node.Id)
                      Length
                      road (ROAD.Id) (to what road belongs)
```

Outer Model:

```
Table: ROAD           Table: Crossroad              Table:REGION
Id                    point (NODE.Id)               Id
Level                 Id                            Name  
Name                                                Level
                                                    Parent (REGION.Id)
```

Comment: first time hearing about inner model, do you have example or base from where I can start?

Comment: @user1765876 look edition. I would start from the class diagram, not data model.